# Javascript and css accessible dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a page that does not have a page load while navigating through the menu items, I solve this with a PHP include, ie I load the html pages. I would like to use the following drop-down menu for this.
The problem is that after clicking on the menu item that the hover opens, the drop-down menu does not disappear.
Thank you for the solutions!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    
        // Remove no-js class
        $('html').removeClass('no-js');
    
     $('#toggleMenu').on('click', function() {
    
            if ( $(this).hasClass('js-open') ) {
    
                $('#nav > ul > li:not(#toggleMenu)').removeClass('js-showElement');
                $(this).removeClass('js-open');
    
                $(this).attr('aria-expanded', false);
    
            } else {
    
                $('#nav > ul > li:not(#toggleMenu)').addClass('js-showElement');
                $(this).addClass('js-open');
    
                $(this).attr('aria-expanded', true);
    
            }
    
      return false; 
     })
    
        // Add plus mark to li that have a sub menu
        $('nav ul li:has("ul") > a').append('<span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>');
    
    
    
    
        // sub menu
     // ------------------------
    
        // When interacting with a li that has a sub menu
        $('nav ul li:has("ul")').on('mouseover keyup click mouseleave', function(e) {
    
            console.log("test")
    
         // If either -
          // tabbing into the li that has a sub menu
          // hovering over the li that has a sub menu
         if ( e.keyCode === 9 | e.type === 'mouseover' ) {
    
          // Show sub menu
          $(this).children('ul').removeClass('js-hideElement');
                $(this).children('ul').addClass('js-showElement');
         }
    
      // If mouse leaves li that has sub menu
      if ( e.type === 'mouseleave' ) {
    
       // hide sub menu
       $(this).children('ul').removeClass('js-showElement');
                $(this).children('ul').addClass('js-hideElement');
      }
    
    
      // If clicking on li that has a sub menu
      if ( e.type === 'click' ) {
    
       // If sub menu is already open
       if ( $(this).children('a').hasClass('js-openSubMenu') ) {
    
                    // remove Open class
        $(this).children('a').removeClass('js-openSubMenu');
    
        // Hide sub menu
           $(this).children('ul').removeClass('js-showElement');
                 $(this).children('ul').addClass('js-hideElement');
    
    
       // If sub menu is closed
       } else {
    
                    // add Open class
        $(this).children('a').addClass('js-openSubMenu');
    
        // Show sub menu
           $(this).children('ul').removeClass('js-hideElement');
                 $(this).children('ul').addClass('js-showElement');
    
       }
    
      } // end click event
    
        });
     
    
        // Tabbing through Levels of sub menu
     // ------------------------
    
        // If key is pressed while on the last link in a sub menu
        $('li > ul > li:last-child > a').on('keydown', function(e) {
    
    
         // If tabbing out of the last link in a sub menu AND not tabbing into another sub menu
         if ( (e.keyCode == 9) && $(this).parent('li').children('ul').length == 0 ) {
    
        // Close this sub menu
              $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').removeClass('js-showElement');
                    $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').addClass('js-hideElement');
    
    
          // If tabbing out of a third level sub menu and there are no other links in the parent (level 2) sub menu
          if ( $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').parent('li').parent('ul').parent('li').children('ul').length > 0 
            && $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').parent('li').is(':last-child') ) {
    
            // Close the parent sub menu (level 2) as well
            $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').parent('li').parent('ul').removeClass('js-showElement');
                        $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').parent('li').parent('ul').addClass('js-hideElement');
          }
    
         }
    
        })
    
    })
    
    
    // Focus on keyboard only
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
     document.documentElement.classList.remove('as-mouseuser');
     document.documentElement.classList.add('as-keyboarduser');
    });
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
     document.documentElement.classList.remove('as-keyboarduser');
     document.documentElement.classList.add('as-mouseuser');
    });
```

```css
    nav {
     position: relative;
     max-width: 100%;
     display: block;
    }
    
    nav ul, nav li {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
    }
    
    nav li {
     position: relative;
     /* float: left; */
     text-align: left;
    }
    
    nav a {
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 13px 15px;
     color: #58729B;
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    /* Any sub menu */
    a + ul {
     position: absolute;
    }
    
    a + ul:not(.js-showElement) {
     display: none;
    }
    
    /* The Main Navigation Bar - Navigation Level One */
    nav > ul, .fa {
     height: 100%;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li {
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
     width: auto;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li > a {
     background-color: #fff;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li > a:hover,
    nav > ul > li > a:focus,
    nav > ul > li > a.js-openSubMenu {
     background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li:hover > a,
    nav > ul > li:focus > a {
     background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li:not(:last-child) {
     border-bottom: none;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li:not(#toggleMenu):not(.js-showElement) {
     display: inline-block;
    }
    
    nav #toggleMenu {
     display: none;
    }
    
    span#toggleMenu-text {
     position: absolute;
     opacity: 0;
    }
    
    /* Second Level Dropdown */
    nav > ul > li > ul {
     background-color: #fff;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     box-shadow: 0 10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    
    nav > ul > li > ul {
     top: 40px;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li > ul > li > a {
     display: block;
     width: 180px;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover,
    nav > ul > li > ul > li > a:focus {
     background-color: #f1f1f1;
     display: block;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li > ul > li:not(:last-child) a {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    
    /* Third Level Dropdown */
    nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
     top: 0;
     left: 180px;
     background-color: #fff;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     box-shadow: 0 10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
     
    nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a {
     display: block;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover,
    nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a:focus {
     background-color: #f1f1f1;
     display: block;
     width: 180px;
    }
    
    nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li:not(:last-child) > a {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    
    /* Javascript classes */
    nav > ul > li.js-hideElement {
     display: none;
    }
    
    /* Fallback for users without javascript */
    html.no-js li:hover > a + ul,
    html.no-js li:focus > a + ul {
     display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html lang="hu">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav role="navigation">
        <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-list" id="nav">
         <div class="nav-list-top">
         </div>
         <li><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" aria-haspopup="true">Top menu</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown" aria-label="submenu">
           <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
          </ul>
         </li>
         </ul>
    </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: do you want to display the sub menu on hover or on click ?

Comment: check this its using jquery http://html-tuts.com/demo/jquery-dropdown-menu/hover-slide/

Comment: Viira I want show sub menu on hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is add this extra on:

// If sub menu is already open

```
   if ( $(this).children('a').hasClass('js-openSubMenu') || $(this).children('ul').hasClass('js-showElement')) { ... }
```

else { ... }

Thank you everything.